# What do "2 of 6" and "4 of 6" mean in the context of this tennis schedule?

Tags: tennis, atp

I was looking at the ATP tournament schedule at the below two links.

- http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/scores/current/rotterdam/407/results
- http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/scores/current/sofia/7434/results

One of them shows "2 of 6" and the other shows "4 of 6" at the top. What does it mean? I couldn't find the answer to this searching the internet.

Comment: Note to editors: please not imply searching the intertnet is the same thing as using google. There are alternative search engines and it would benefit people if they realize this and start checking alternatives. And I can't recommend the micro$oft search engine but other engines that better respect user privacy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numbers that confuse you have nothing to do with the tournament schedule per se. The link you are viewing shows ongoing ATP tournaments. There are 6 ATP tournaments that are currently ongoing, which I have listed below.

- Open Sud de France (1 of 6)
- Garanti Koza Sofia Open (2 of 6)
- Ecuador Open (3 of 6)
- ABN Amro World Tennis Tournament (4 of 6)
- Memphis Open (5 of 6)
- Argentina Open (6 of 6)

In the page component that shows these numbers, there are navigational buttons that let you navigate from one tournament to the next. I hope that clears your confusion.

Comment: oh, very strange. I didn't think about it because Sofia Open completed before Rotterdam Open began or maybe not the main part. Probably they overlapped a little. Thank you for the answer. I couldn't figure.